# Use Message ID to upload Emote in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my first time on this website, so apologies if I've done anything incorrectly.

I'm trying to create a command where I can input a message ID (`!command [message ID]`) and the bot with search for new emotes in that message and add them to the server. I'm inexperienced in this as well, so please be aware of that and be specific when you can.

Thank you,
Red

Answer (score 0):

1. The message needs to be either in the same server or in a server the bot is in
2. If the message is in the same server, will it be in the same channel?
3. How will the message contain emotes? Emotes from other servers or images? If its emotes from other servers I don't believe the bot can access it unless it's also in the server

Here's a start:
`const specifiedMsg = msg.channel.messages.fetch(id);`